# Cypress and Docker - Can't run because no spec files were found

Tags: docker-compose, cypress

I'm trying to run cypress tests inside a docker container. I've simplified my setup so I can just try to get a simple container instance running and a few tests executed.

I'm using docker-compose

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  e2e:
    image: test/e2e:v1
    command: ["./node_modules/.bin/cypress", "run", "--spec", "integration/mobile/all.js"]
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cypress
    container_name: cypress
    network_mode: host
```

and my Dokerfile-cypress

```
FROM cypress/browsers:chrome69

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install cypress@3.1.0

COPY cypress /usr/src/app/cypress
COPY cypress.json /usr/src/app/cypress

RUN ./node_modules/.bin/cypress verify
```

when I run `docker-compose up` after I build my image I see

```
cypress | name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted
cypress | Can't run because no spec files were found.
cypress |
cypress | We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:
cypress |
cypress | integration/mobile/all-control.js
cypress exited with code 1
```

I've verified that my cypress files and folders have been copied over and I can verify that my test files exist. I've been stuck on this for a while and i'm unsure what to do besides giving up.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out cypress automatically checks for `/cypress/integration` folder. Moving all my cypress files inside this folder got it working.

*** **UPDATE July 2023** ***

If you are using the latest cypress (version 12) the correct file path location is now `/cypress/e2e folder`

You may also need to change your test files to `example.cy.ts`

Comment: Moving files inside `/cypress/integration` got it working

Answer (score 5):

**The problem**: No cypress specs files were found on your automation suite.

**Solution**: Cypress Test files are located in `cypress/integration` by default, but can be configured to another directory.
In this folder insert your suites per section:

for example:

```
 - cypress/integration/billing-scenarios-suite
 - cypress/integration/user-management-suite
 - cypress/integration/proccesses-and-handlers-suite
```

I assume that these suite directories contains sub directories (which represents some micro logic) ,therefore you need to run it recursively to gather all files:

```
cypress run --spec \
cypress/integration/<your-suite>/**/* , \
cypress/integration/<your-suite>/**/**/*
```

If you run in cypress on docker verify that cypress volume contains the tests and mapped and mounted in container on `volume` section (on Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml file) and run it properly:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> cypress run --spec \
cypress/integration/<your-suite>/**/* , \
cypress/integration/<your-suite>/**/**/*
```

Answer (score 3):

After migrating from an older version of Cypress (8 to 12), I had to rename the `cypress/integration` folder to `cypress/e2e` and the spec files from `*.spec.ts` to `*.cy.ts`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've also updated my answer as well to account for the latest version of cypress.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you  CLICK AND DRAG file method to get file path in VSC, then it generates path with SMALL c-drive letter and this causes error: "Can't run because no spec files were found. + We searched for specs matching this glob pattern:"

e.g. by click and drag I get:

```
cypress run --spec c:\Users\dmitr\Desktop\cno-dma-replica-for-cy-test\cypress\integration\dma-playground.spec.js
```

Notice SMALL c, in above.

BUT if I use right click 'get path', I get BIG C, and it works for some reason:

```
cypress run --spec C:\Users\dmitr\Desktop\cno-dma-replica-for-cy-test\cypress\integration\dma-playground.spec.js
```

and this causes it to work.

Its strange I know, but there you go.

but if you just use: